# Cell Merging in AG-GRID

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I want to merge cells in ag-grid using native JS.If I select multiple cells and click on a button for merging then cell should get merged in order of there selection.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported on ag-grid, as it is not really focused in edition (although it has [some stuff](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-editing/index.php)) but rather on data visualization. In other words, this can not replace MS Excel, at least not right now ;)

Comment: yeah you are right but i was thinking to replace excel ;)

Comment: It would be hard to implement since the whole idea is to virtualize the rows, meaning that ag-grid doesn't "remember" the rows but rather build them from scratch every time. So the merging would have to be acknowledged at a data level, which is not the purpose of the grid. I'm sorry you can't replace excel, at least not in this sense :)

Comment: I have manipulated the code of the ag-grid to remember the data using data structures and i have added the calculation functionality to the grid.It also remembers the formula used in that calculation just like the excel.And i hope I can solve the merging issue in the ag-grid by memorization technique.

Comment: I usually default to [duck typing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) on these cases, specially if you're dealing with javascript. If you can make the grid do what you want, but you don't have the specific object, you just make that up and shove it up the methods.